# data types in ternary operators in Java

Tags: java

```
char alpha = 'A';
int foo = 65;
boolean trueExp = true;
System.out.println(trueExp ? alpha : 0);
System.out.println(trueExp ? alpha : foo);
```

Can somebody explain why the first output is'A' but the second one is 65?

I tried different values of foo and it tirns out it doesn't matter. 65 is exactly the Ascii code for letter 'A'. What I don't understand is why in the first output the 'A' is treated as Ascii code but in the second one it's not.

Comment: the ternary operator is a condensed form of if-else that _returns a value_. Meaning, when you are using an int and a char together, it casts the char to an int value (ascii) since you cant return two different types. This should be an implicit cast. though I m not too sure why nothing happens when you use the primitive int literal 0

Comment: ok, i did some reading up and based on what i read: alpha is a char and 0 is a value that fits into a char (int literal is a compile time constant) so it is still a char, however, if you use a int variable,  because an int has a range of values that does not fit into a char, but a char can fit into the int, the char 'A' gets promoted to an int and the overall returned value is an int

Comment: You can try testing it out with the following `System.out.println(trueExp ? alpha : 65536); System.out.println(trueExp ? alpha : foo);` where 65536 is the max int value a char variable can store + 1

Comment: I m kinda waiting for a more experienced member of SO to give an in depth answer, because i m kinda having a hard time putting it into words and using correct terminology

Comment: in short: since the literal `0` is a valid `char`, the expression can/will result in a `char` (if you used `-1` or a value greater than `65535`, which is not a valid `char`, the result will be an `int` - the first operand must be converted to `int`). For the second case, there is no option: the *smallest* type for `char` and `int` is `int`

Comment: For details, see the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25.2): " If one of the operands is of type T where T is byte, short, or char, and the other operand is a constant expression (§15.29) of type int whose value is representable in type T, then the type of the conditional expression is T. ... Otherwise, general numeric promotion (§5.6) is applied to the second and third operands, and the type of the conditional expression is the promoted type of the second and third operands."

Comment: Thanks for all the answering, I think I figure it out. You guys are the best!